# Module Folder in Sharepoint is not deployed with the wsp file

Tags: solution-package, module

I am updating my solutions from Sharepoint 2010 to 2013. I needed to make a little workaround because SP 2013 refused to find my pictures in the images folder. So I created a module folder for SP 2013 and check for the version. That works all fine like this:

```
 if (SPVersion == 15)
                {
                    Blog.NoPortraitPath = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/SP15Pics/NoPortrait.png";
                }
                else
                {
                   Blog.NoPortraitPath = this.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "Blog.Images.NoPortrait.png");
                }
```

But my problem is, that when i want to install the solution with a wsp file this module folder is not integrated like when i deploy it out of VS 2012. The files are set to "embedded recource" as build action.